# I can't delete a file that I create by accident

Tags: cmd.exe, regex, window

By accident I create a file that I named "(?=(.*[a-z]))(?=(.*[A-Z]))(?=(.*[0-9]))(?=(.*[!@#$%^&*()-__+.]))." is a regex declaration. I wanted to create a file with the touch command with another name but by accident I pasted it. Now I can't delete the file and apparently the file doesn't exist.

This is what "dir" shows

```
17/06/2021  03:56                 0 (=(.[a-z]))(=(.[A-Z]))(=(.[0-9]))(=(.[!@#$%^&()-__+.])).
```

An this is what "ls -l" shows

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 wrrnrtm 197121       0 Jun 17 03:56 '(?=(.*[a-z]))(?=(.*[A-Z]))(?=(.*[0-9]))(?=(.*[!@#$%^&*()-__+.])).'
```

I tried to delete it whit the file explorer and the console whit "rm" and "del" but nothing. Any suggestions?

edit:
I posted in the wrong community so I post again here

Comment: Create a new, test Windows User Account (Profile). Make this account a member of Administrators. Log into the new Account and try deleting the file from the new Account.

Comment: What happens when you copy the `ls` output (with the single quotes surrounding the filename) and paste it as the argument of the `rm` command? But I do like @Joseph Gould's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Cut every other file out of the parent folder that contains you odd file, then delete the parent folder instead of just the one file.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved it by using a wildcard, like so `del "(?=*"`